# Map multiple associations in one instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way of mapping multiple associations in the one instance?

For example:

```
@sale.sale_selections.flat_map { |ss| (ss.drinks + ss.food).map { |d, f| d.water, f.cake }}
```

**Sale model**

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sale_selections, allow_destroy: true
  has_many :drinks, through: : sale_selections
  has_many :foods, through: : sale_selections
end
```

Comment: `drinks` and `food` belong to the same model?

Comment: Yes. Both belong to sale_selections.

Answer (score 0):

```
@sale.sale_selections.flat_map { |ss| 
  (ss.drinks + ss.food).map { |d| 
     [d.water, d.cake] 
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution gives me an error: undefined method `d.cake'. I've added the Sale model info above.

Comment: Sorry, full error is: undefined method `cake' for #<DrinkMethod:0x007fd3e0d65e00>

Comment: seems like drinks and foods do not belong to the same model like you said above

Comment: Apologies. I should of been more clearer to begin with. I added the model with associations to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
@sale.sale_selections.map { |ss| ss.drinks.map(&:water) + ss.food.map(&:cake) }.flatten
```